# Check if a key/value exists in helm chart yaml and add a value to it if exists, otherwise create a new key-pair value

Tags: yaml, annotations, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Let's say that I have the following structure in one helm template file

```
{{- define "deployAnnotations" -}}  
"key1" : "value1",  
"key2" : "value2"  
"ip_range": "20.20.20.20/32"  
{{- end -}}
```

and the above are included in the deployment.yaml file of my helm chart

```
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations: 
         {{ include "podAnnotations" . | nindent 8 }}
```

Now I want to add one more annotation that also define in a template file the following one:

```
{{- define "ipdeployAnnotations" -}}  
ip_range: 10.10.10.10/32  
{{- end -}}
```

My question is how can I search if **ip_range** exists in the **podAnnotations** structure. If exists I just want to add the 10.10.10.10/32 to the existing line , otherwise I would like to create a new one.

I imagine something like below but **in** operator is not working for me , and also I do not know how to add the additional value to **ip_range**

```
template:    
    metadata:    
      annotations:     
         {{ include "podAnnotations" . | nindent 8 }}  
         {{ - if "ip_range" in "podAnnotations" }}  
         // do something in order to have the following result  
         "ip_range": "20.20.20.20/32", "10.10.10.10/32"
         {{- else }}
          {{ include "ipdeployAnnotations" . | nindent 8 }} 
         {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may convert it to a struct first, and then use it in the way of manipulating dictionary.

templates/_helper.tpl

```yaml
{{- define "deployAnnotations" -}}
"key1" : "value1"
"key2" : "value2"
"ip_range": "20.20.20.20/32"
{{- end -}}

{{- define "ipdeployAnnotations" -}}
ip_range: "10.10.10.10/32"
{{- end -}}
```

templates/xxx.yaml

```yaml
...
{{- $da :=  (include "deployAnnotations" . | fromYaml) }}
{{- $ida :=  (include "ipdeployAnnotations" . | fromYaml) }}
{{- if (hasKey $da "ip_range") }}
{{- $_ := set $da "ip_range" (printf "%s, %s" $da.ip_range $ida.ip_range) }}
{{- else }}
{{- $_ := set $da "ip_range" $ida.ip_range }}
{{- end }}
{{- range $k, $v := $da }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
{{- end }}
...
```

output

```yaml
ip_range: 20.20.20.20/32, 10.10.10.10/32
key1: value1
key2: value2
```